# Error on creation of a mapping for an index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to change the mapping of an index, but getting an error.  Here are the steps I am taking to create the index

- create the index by populating it through a python script
- set the mapping with this code:

  ```
  PUT /myidx/orderrow/_mapping
  {
      "orderrow": {
          "properties": {
              "item_code": {
                  "type": "string", 
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Here's the error message I get:

```
{
   "error": "MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [item_code] has different index values, mapper [item_code] has different `norms.enabled` values, mapper [item_code] has different tokenize values, mapper [item_code] has different index_analyzer]}]",
   "status": 400
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because you are indexing data first into the index, Elasticsearch is auto-detecting the field type/mapping for your `item_code` field based on the data being loaded. Then when you attempt to update the mapping, you are getting the error shown above.

I would recommend creating the index and applying the mapping prior to running your Python script to populate the index.

```
PUT /myproj/

PUT /myproj/orderrow/_mapping
 {
    "orderrow": {
        "properties": {
            "item_code": {
                "type": "string", 
                 "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
     }
  }
```

Alternately, you can force the conflicting mapping into your index, using the `ignore_conflicts` option as defined in the [merging & conflicts section of the Put Mapping API Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#merging-conflicts). However, I am not sure how that will impact the already indexed documents.

Comment: I didn't know that I could create the mapping first, and that is a better approach in my mind.  I will do that.  Thanks!

Comment: I used `ignore_conflicts` for changing `store` value of existing property to `true` but in spite of `acknoleged : true` nothing changed.

Comment: `ignore_conflicts` has been removed https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11203

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and resolved it deleting the mapping and creating it (Warning: Deleting a mapping will **delete all documents (rows)** with that mapping)

```
DELETE /myidx/orderrow/_mapping

PUT /myidx/orderrow/_mapping -d '
...
'
```

After that, I had to close and open the index:

```
POST /myidx/_close
POST /myidx/_open
```

Comment: NB: that when you delete a mapping for a type, you also delete all documents of that type in the index. see: https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime#_delete_the_mapping

Comment: Your comment should come before his answer... Aaaand all my documents are now gone.

Comment: According to the 6.4 docs, it "is no longer possible to delete the mapping for a type. Instead you should delete the index and recreate it with the new mappings."